# Why Unbound Local error is showing up, where I expect NameError should be raised?

Tags: python-3.x

When I delete the variable and access it inside function the unboundLocalError shows up where as if do the same thing outside the function NameError is raised.I am not able to understand why there is inconsistency in behaviour to access the deleted Variable?

```
def func():
    x=10
    del x
    print(x)
func() #this will cause UnboundLocal Error

#But if i copy the same code and execute it without using the function call then NameError shows up

x=10
del x
print(x) #this will raise NameError as x does not exist
```

According to me in both cases NameError should be raised as we are trying to access the variable after deleting the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Raised when a reference is made to a local variable in a function or method, but no value has been bound to that variable. This is a subclass of NameError.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror

The difference seems to be one of purely location. UnboundLocalError extends the NameError and UnboundLocalError is chosen as the error when it occurs inside a method/function.

This might not settle a separate question: "Why did python dev's decide to do this this way" But it does explain why you're seeing it.

Comment: I really should make habit to read documentation.By the way thanks Dave, I am satisfied by your answer. ;)